# How to handle large amount of documents stored in a database?

Tags: mysql, database, bigdata

I am working on one application where user can scan/upload documents. Application processes those documents and store it in the database. We are using MySQL database.
Right now we are having more than 200,000 documents in the database. So we are facing difficulties maintaining such large number of documents.
What can be done for this issue? Can 'Big data' be a solution?

Comment: Don't store documents in the database. Store file names in the database. Use the file system to store documents. There is absolutely no good reason to store documents in a database, and plenty of good reasons not to. If one of my reports did that, I would discuss their future.

Comment: @Bohemian Oh come on; there must be *some* good reasons

Comment: @Strawberry maybe if SQL was your only technology and you have no other choice (ie no application code, just queries and a layer that produces web forms), but it's still not a *good* reason. You can't "update" or "query" the data, it would colossally bloat your database backup size, backup time, logs, database transaction times, reduce I/O performance (row size would be massive)... I am only warming up here. It's such a terrible idea for all sorts of reasons, if by bad luck you find yourself considering it, find another way.

Answer (score 2):

The common practice is to just store the path to the document in the database and put document in some location in the disk.